# android switch from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two layout xml files, each with its own separate Activity class. Each class is valid, because I can refer to each activity from the application section of the manifest file and it launches and works. My problem is when I click a button on the first layout xml file to go to the other one - it will switch to the second layout xml file, but any actions on that layout do nothing. The code in the second activity class doesn't fire. For example, when I have MenuActivity listed first, it will display the layout xml file, and all calls on that layout work. When I click the button to switch to Home, it will display the home layout xml file, but all code within HomeActivity does nothing. I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't put my finger on it. Thanks in advance.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: Can you show what code you are currently using to switch Activities?

Comment: Can you show us some relevant parts from `MenuActivity` and `HomeActivity` ?

Comment: You should post the code that does the switching, not just the XML

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you are using [`setContentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) instead of [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to switch Activities.

For example, to launch your `MenuActivity` from your `HomeActivity`:

```
Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
startActivity(menuIntent);
```

`setContentView()` simply changes the display layout; it does not create a new Activity.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That was it. When I add your code, though, I get this error: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MenuActivity>) is undefined. TextView menuButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMenu); menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class); startActivity(menuIntent); } }); Sorry, I don't know how to format this properly.

Comment: new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class); needs a context 'this' and a class 'MenuActivity.class'. it seems like you aren't giving it a proper context. try getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Tanis: What a guess!

Comment: Thanks, that was it. This code is within HomeActivity.onCreate(). Is this the correct location for this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can do it (more or less) wherever you deem appropriate. As David pointed out, all you need is a valid Context.

Comment: Thanks, Tanix.7x. I appreciate everyone's advice. I can move on with further development now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent class to switch from one activity to another.
Suppose your first activity is HomeActivity and you want to go to MenuActivity just write a simple 2 line code..

```
Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

I hope this works.